# SAML Azure configured as service provider and SP logout is not redirecting to the IBM ISAM IDP SSO page after logging out from SP Azure

Tags: azure, saml, logout, identity-management, isam

SAML Azure SP initiated logout is not redirecting to the IBM ISAM IDP SSO page after logging out from SP Azure

any idea where to redirect to sso IBM ISAM IDP SSO page after azure logout from saml.

this was configured correctly the ibm idp logout url
LogOffUri                              : https://idpdomain.com/logoff

in saml tracer, i can see a get line with this idp logout page with http 200 and not 302 redirect.

GET https://webapps.idpdomain.com/logoff?SAMLRequest=lZJRa4MwFIX%2fiuQ9GqOxbVCho3TI2g3WsrG9jKjXzqGJ80bWnz%2b17GEwCnu5D4d7zv3ISYyqbTq5Mycz2Ef4HACtk20S8rYUrFyEOac55z4NQwFUCc4o8yFaAAv9ZV4Q5wl6rI1OCHcZcTLEATKNVmk7SowHlC0p50ceSLGSQeSyhXglzma8UmtlZ%2be7tR1Kz%2fuCXHUduo0aXCgHt8m9ZsSqKuKc20ajnFETMvRaGoU1Sq1aQGkLeVjvd3IkkF1vrClMQ9J4Zukv1usmhQj9xELSaa2CEvqZTe7rojdoKvugm1pD7F1C0%2fh%2bDMk2ztb0rbLX0yelLmk1r8puei%2b0oC35J9rHAW%2bil6Nas4e9f7i9s89iuzolSexdYNL4UuUBcGok0yWc02GoS7%2fKGc95NDa3VNQfJ1VFEdFc8ChQImBqJWLvD%2fOP%2bOtzpN8%3d&Signature=e%2bBwHpuKIh%2fG2WdJ46Kr%2fMu7VJQ3oFnvPevv6gR8BsAwQSHtH4g7REz%2fZSSmrBenjFB7o7viTszWTIEY5N6yAJ%2bnUUfiZ%2b4Sml6cBLpoC2na5OB7LwdGx9G%2fCb29L91fZ%2f4CiSIj4hW5U2lto5T9rT9NtbDBu%2f6cJatLbSJ9wjmV1Ml%2fkvkXxemHC6Su42qvLE7OwLVBVaMXaZ1RRI%2fLU24ok5rsp5r6Ean1m2zFXgqhPiUms0naCN2W5yBbjGcbqWswhfHnAbD0iTnnphSMeGv0c%2fcG9Ue%2fmjvWXw%2bxIRqQ2LdBCmsGKPKME666pBvvy1iqZ6%2fAf7LEbrsejgILXQ%3d%3d&SigAlg=http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2000%2f09%2fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1 HTTP/1.1
Host: webapps.idpdomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 11365
content-type: text/html
date: Tue, 22 Aug 2023 23:59:36 GMT
x-frame-options: DENY
x-content-type-options: nosniff
cache-control: no-store
x-xss-protection: 1
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PD-S-SESSION-ID=0_8/F92MuBi3Q4VC0QDatlEHK4q999anZcBfdxmwj0XTiqmEJh/sU=_AAAAAQA=_mUe/aR3Kq/HJjaI+bGTDJQvojzI=; Domain=.idpdomain.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
TS0115520a=0155c0894a0a3c11888bc29adb1dba15d6b2be2d906953da737e66e064db354d49ce7813bdb23bcc72dcdfdf3e42c8372569ba59f3; Path=/; Domain=.webapps.idpdomain.com
TS0115520a026=011387e0afcf47d8e8ebaa19119a3b9c4f8e906491bbb703283c54cb20cf7e944058f06a69ed89bec2edeed0b2b389e4b446a2cb7f5501f9e644671aa479f2443789297322; Path=/; Domain=.webapps.idpdomain.com
TS56604255027=088b009c34ab20009998f9fc2fc2f5bad35b9e08d0bf8cb9c55b82948ebea09c302a8e5826ae296308026eb5d9113000c2347cbe3787de8113685926af426b8f511d837ba464c590b6cb42133536ee21fb46d46b8b1dbadd19607ce4a44751c8;Path=/
p3p: CP="NON CUR OTPi OUR NOR UNI", CP="{}"

Logout should redirect to IDP sso url after logout from azure